# Css static in html use django, css no show out

Tags: html, css, django, django-staticfiles

main.html

with `{% load static %}` at top and `{% static 'css/main.css' %}` in link css href

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CM1</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="test/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
  </head>

  <body>
    {% include "accounts/navbar.html" %}

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock content %}

    <hr>
    <h5>Our footer</h5>

  </body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

setting.py

```
import os


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles', #<-- already have  
    ...
]

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),
)
```

also STATICFILES_DIRS bracket should be () or []?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did wrong in link tag.

change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="test/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}"> #You did wrong in type. and according to your structure your css filename is index.css
```

To this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}"> #changed main.css to index.css according to your structure
```

Your settings must be like below.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

Comment: i add but no work

Comment: Is your static folder inside project root?

Comment: project -> file -> template -> index.html
project -> static -> css -> index.css
( this is my file and folder place )

Comment: your css filename is index.css but you added main.css. change it

Comment: updated my answer try that

Comment: that is example in the question is main.css

Comment: have you tried my updated answer

Comment: there is only one fault in type in link tag. you wrote type="test/css" that is wrong. It must be type="text/css"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250009/discussion-between-bot-and-manoj-tolagekar).